# Unable to Install Ubuntu on Rog Strix G15

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, laptop, asus, usb-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu LTS 22.04.3, but when I click on "Install Ubuntu" in the installation page, the following error pops up:
[Error in the Booting Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX6Wp.jpg)

I turned off Fast Boot and even created a free space at the end of my SSD, [SS from Disk Management.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6CwO.png)

I made my USB bootable using Rufus 4.3P - [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKdFI.png) [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8811.png)

Here are my Specs:

- Laptop: Asus Rog Strix G153RM
- Proc: Ryzen 7 6800H
- Ram: 16gb
- GPU: RTX 3060 (laptop)
- Space Unallocated: 120gb